# Can I use a fetching library like SWR when using ccxt in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swr, ccxt

By using the fetching library, you can take advantage of many benefits such as isLoading, isError, caching, auto refreshing, mutatuion, and conditional fetching.
When using ccxt, I wonder if these benefits can be maintained by using it with the fetching library.

```js
const ccxtBitmex = new ccxt['bitmex']({
  proxyUrl: PROXY_URL,
  apiKey: bitmexApiKey,
  secret: bitmexSecret,
})

export const fetchBalance = async () => {
  return await ccxtBitmex.fetchBalance()
}

// Where is the opportunity to cut in?
```

If this is not possible, it would be difficult to find a reason to use the ccxt library in react. Maybe I should just access the exchange api without ccxt?